# STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED (0xc0000022): Could not connect to - Azure Netapps File Share (Network Drive) access with smbj JAVA library

Tags: java, smb, fileshare, netapp, smbj

Trying to read files from Azure Netapps (Network Drive). We successfully mount and read files with Window File Explorer.

With the same credentials, we are trying with JAVA [smbj](https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj) library.

While executing the java code in eclipse, getting following error,

```
com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException: STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED (0xc0000022): Could not connect to \\AZUREANF.com\imagestorage
.
.
Suppressed: com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException: STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED (0xc0000022): Error closing connection to \\AZUREANF.com\IPC$
```

- Share Server Name - **AZUREANF.com**
- Share Folder - **imagestorage**

The complete logs...

```
[main] INFO com.hierynomus.smbj.connection.PacketEncryptor - Initialized PacketEncryptor with Cipher << AES_128_GCM >>
[main] INFO com.hierynomus.smbj.connection.Connection - Successfully connected to: AZUREANF.com
[main] INFO com.hierynomus.smbj.connection.SMBSessionBuilder - Successfully authenticated TWSpringvale on AZUREANF.com, session is 3250754506031368179
[main] INFO com.hierynomus.smbj.session.Session - Connecting to \\AZUREANF.com\imagestorage on session 3250754506031368179
[main] INFO com.hierynomus.smbj.paths.DFSPathResolver - Attempting to resolve \\AZUREANF.com\imagestorage through DFS
[main] INFO com.hierynomus.smbj.paths.DFSPathResolver - Starting DFS resolution for \\AZUREANF.com\imagestorage
[main] INFO com.hierynomus.smbj.session.Session - Connecting to \\AZUREANF.com\IPC$ on session 3250754506031368179
[main] INFO com.hierynomus.smbj.session.Session - Logging off session 3250754506031368179 from host AZUREANF.com
[main] INFO com.hierynomus.smbj.connection.Connection - Closed connection to AZUREANF.com
[Packet Reader for AZUREANF.com] INFO com.hierynomus.smbj.transport.tcp.direct.DirectTcpPacketReader - Thread[Packet Reader for AZUREANF.com,5,main] stopped.
com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException: STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED (0xc0000022): Could not connect to \\AZUREANF.com\imagestorage
    at com.hierynomus.smbj.session.Session.connectTree(Session.java:151)
    at com.hierynomus.smbj.session.Session.connectShare(Session.java:113)
    at Reader.NetworkFilereader(Reader.java:70)
    at Reader.main(Reader.java:129)
    Suppressed: com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException: STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED (0xc0000022): Error closing connection to \\AZUREANF.com\IPC$
        at com.hierynomus.smbj.share.TreeConnect.close(TreeConnect.java:72)
        at com.hierynomus.smbj.share.Share.close(Share.java:116)
        at com.hierynomus.smbj.session.Session.logoff(Session.java:236)
        at com.hierynomus.smbj.session.Session.close(Session.java:279)
        at com.hierynomus.smbj.connection.Connection.close(Connection.java:178)
        at com.hierynomus.smbj.connection.Connection.close(Connection.java:155)
        at Reader.NetworkFilereader(Reader.java:118)
        ... 1 more
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into the same problem using smbj-0.11.5 with Azure NetApp Files.

There seems to be an issue related to encryption negotiation between the client and the server when 3.1.1 dialect is used (https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj/issues/747).

I suggest trying any of the following workarounds:

- downgrade the SMB dialect to 3.0: `SmbConfig.builder().withDialects(SMB2Dialect.SMB_3_0)`
- enable encryption explicitly (and still use 3.1.1 dialect): `SmbConfig.builder().withEncryptData(true)`

Both worked for me with smbj-0.11.5 and Azure NetApp Files.